# __xl_pow, __xl_log, __xl_exp in perf report

Tags: fortran, powerpc, perf

I work on performance profiling of an application `app` that was compiled with IBM XL Fortran compiler for IBM POWER8 processor. This is a part of the output of `perf report`:

```
 3.88%  app  app                [.] __xl_pow
 2.91%  app  app                [.] __xl_log
 1.81%  app  app                [.] __xl_exp
```

What are these functions shown in the profile? My hypothesis is that these are the implementations of `pow()`, `log()` and `exp()` that are supplied with the compiler (see [a similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239753/perf-report-showing-libm-pow-l9)). Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enable an optimization level of `-O3` or higher, the XL compilers replace several `libm` function calls with calls to a high performance library shipped with the compiler.  The `__xl_*` function calls you're seeing are coming from that library.  If you don't want them, for example because their precision is sometimes slightly different from the libm calls, compile with `-qstrict=library`.

Note:  Even with `-qstrict=library`, XL Fortran might still call its own functions for `pow()`, but these functions have the same precision as `libm`'s `pow()`.

Comment: See also https://community.ibm.com/community/user/power/blogs/archive-user/2018/09/26/6-faqs-about-the-xl-math-functions.